# express-sesison not saving on routes

Tags: node.js, express, express-session

I have a ExpressJS server and I would like to implement in Sessions however it doesn't seem to save the sessions.

The flow is to:

1. POST to /api/login
2. GET from /api/viewSession

However, the `session['stuff']` returns `undefined`.

I suspected it might be because i'm trying to `GET` the session from a different URL. So I added a `GET` method to `/api/login` but it returned `undefined` too.

Could somebody point me in the right direction please? I'm a little lost after a few hours of Googling to no avail.

Here below is my code for `index.js` and my route `api.js`.

Also, I'm using

- NPM - Version 8.3.1
- Node - Version v16.14.0
- `npm i cors` - Version 2.8.5
- `npm i express-session` - Version 1.17.2
- `npm i express` - Version 4.17.3

`index.js`

```
const express = require('express')
const formidable = require('express-formidable');
const cors = require('cors');
const session = require('express-session');

const api = require('./routes/api');

const app = express()
const port = 3000;

app.use(express.json());
app.use(formidable());
app.use(
    cors({
        origin: true,
        optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
        credentials: true,
    })
);
app.options(
    '*',
    cors({
        origin: true,
        optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
        credentials: true,
    })
);
app.use(
    session({
        saveUninitialized: false,
        secret: "anyrandomstring",
        cookie: { maxAge: 36000000 }
    })
);

//Routes
app.use('/api', api);

//Navigation
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index');
    res.send("Hi!");
})

//App Start
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`App Listening on port ${port}`);
})
```

`api.js`

```
"use strict";
const express = require("express");
let router = express.Router();

router
.route('/dump')
.post(async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.fields);
    res.send({status: "ok"})
})

router
.route('/login')
.post(async (req, res) => {
    //Saving in Session
    req.session['stuff'] = "123456";

    res.send("Ok");
})

router
.route('/viewSession')
.get((req, res) => {
    console.log(req.session['stuff']);
    res.send("ok");
})

module.exports = router;
```

Also, this is the way I send the POST/GET request

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://localhost:3000" + '/api/login',
  type: "POST",
  crossDomain: true,
  dataType: "json",
  data: {},
  success: function (response) {
     console.log(response);
  }
})
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem, seems to work fine with the code you're posting. Is your client storing the cookie properly?

Comment: @robertklep would It help if i just dump the entire code here? Because I removed some stuff that was using the `cors` module from npm. Not sure if that one was the cause of this problem or not.

Comment: Don't dump the entire code, make a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @robertklep Alright, I've cleaned out the code and included the versions of the modules I'm using. I've edited my question. Hopefully you are able to reproduce the problem now.

Answer (score 1):

If you're making cross-domain requests with `XMLHttpRequest` and you want to allow cookies to be set by the server handling the request, you need to set [`withCredentials : true`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials).

Using jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://localhost:3000" + '/api/login',
  type: "POST",
  crossDomain: true,
  xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
  dataType: "json",
  data: {},
  success: function (response) {
     console.log(response);
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however this doesn't seem to work :/ the `req.session['stuff'] still shows up undefined`

Comment: I just tried using Postman and it works. However using jQuery on a browser doesn't work. I'm so confused. does this have something to do with jQuery not properly sending credentials?

Comment: It works for me. The issue is that unless explicitly specified, no cookies will be allowed with cross-domain XMLHttpRequest calls ("XMLHttpRequest responses from a different domain cannot set cookie values for their own domain unless withCredentials is set to true before making the request").

Comment: Oh, I found out the root cause to the issue and like you said yes it's because the Ajax Request to `/api/login` does not actually set the cookies in my browser. So I had to set `sameSite: 'none'` in my ExpressJS code.